# Single Sign out with oauth2 on spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have integrate my application with cloud foundry UAA server by using oauth2 protocol. I found it's easy to do single sign in , but not sign out. This sounds awkward to me. Any elegant way to implement sign out, I would prefer to sign out for ALL applications which integrate with UAA.